# Chart min max values from each given day using crossfilter and dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a dataset that looks something like this and want to make a line chart with with maximum and minimum temperatures per day (there are multiple readings per day).

```
[..., 
{datetime: '21 Feb...', surface_temperature:21.5},
{datetime: '21 Feb...', surface_temperature:21.9},
{datetime: '21 Feb...', surface_temperature:25.5},
...
{datetime: '22 Feb...', surface_temperature:23.5},
....
]
```

how can I get the min and max values of surface_temperature using crossfilter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easiest to use a helper library like [Reductio](https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio#aggregations-standard-aggregations-reductio-b-median-b-i-boolean-i-i-value-i-), which will generate reduce functions for these and other aggregations.

The [dc.js FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/faq#do-reductions-that-require-all-the-row-data) has a pretty extensive discussion on the topic if you want to do this manually. It's not easy to get right for incremental aggregations.

Comment: Disclaimer: I wrote Reductio, so my recommendation may be biased ;-)

Comment: My data set has multiple values for surface_temp depending on time. I want to get three scalars for every day (min, max, and median). Following the docs on Reductio, I have: ```reductio().min(...).max(...).median(...)``` and specified valueAccessor for dc.js chart but it only displays the median and the console throws a warning ```VALUELIST accessor is being overwritten by median aggregation```

Comment: That's basically correct. It will trigger warnings, but should be alright. If you want to avoid the warnings, go with `reductio().min(function (d) { return d.surface_temperature; }).max(true).median(true) (dateGrp);`

Comment: How does it work if I need a multi line chart (one line each for min, max, and median)? Right now I see only one line.

Comment: You need to use the value accessor on the chart for your first line. Then create additional "stacks" on your dc.js chart using the same group and a different value accessor. https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.stackMixin+stack

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107231/discussion-between-siddharth-shukla-and-ethan-jewett).

Comment: Sorry, chat kind of sucks on mobile :-( For the new DC question you should probably post a new question anyway.  Cheers.